# What is the difference between single quote identifiers and double-quote in ClojureScript?

Tags: string, dom, clojure, element, clojurescript

Suppose I have the following HTML document element and the DOM is loaded:

```
<ul id='myUnorderedList' />
```

When I run the following code in Clojure

```
(def my-element (.getElementById js/document 'myUnorderedList'))
```

The value of `my-element` is `nil`.

But this works:

```
(def my-element (.getElementById js/document "myUnorderedList"))
```

ie `my-element` has a value of `#object[HTMLUListElement [object HTMLUListElement]]`.

```
(def my-element (.getElementById js/document "myUnorderedList"))
```

My question is: **What is the difference between single quote identifiers and double-quote in ClojureScript?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as single quote identifiers in Clojure and ClojureScript. To create a string, you MUST use double quotes (unlike for example in JavaScript, where you can use either, as long as the opening and closing quote match).

What you have created with `'myUnorderedList'` is the symbol `myUnorderedList'`, as symbols are created with a leading single quote.
You can read more about symbols here:

http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Symbols